# In Python, how do I create a list of files based on specified file extensions?

Tags: python, list, file, dictionary, types

Let's say I have a folder with a bunch of files (with different file extensions). I want to create a list of files from this folder. However, I want to create a list of files with SPECIFIC file extensions.

These file extensions are categorized into groups.

File Extensions: .jpg, .png, .gif, .pdf, .raw, .docx, .pptx, .xlsx, .js, .html, .css

Group "image" contains .jpg, .png, .gif.
Group "adobe" contains .pdf, .raw. (yes, I'm listing '.raw' as an adobe file for this example :P)
Group "microsoft" contains .docx, .pptx, .xlsx.
Group "webdev" contains .js, .html, .css.

I want to be able to add these files types to a list. That list will be generated in a ".txt" file and would contain ALL files with the chosen file extensions.

So if my folder has 5 image files, 10 adobe files, 5 microsoft files, 3 webdev files and I select  the "image" and "microsoft" groups, this application in Python would create a .txt file that contains a list of filenames with file extensions that belong only in the image and microsoft groups.

The text file would have a list like below:

picture1.jpg
picture2.png
picture3.gif
picture4.jpg
picture5.jpg
powerpoint.pptx
powerpoint2.pptx
spreadsheet.xlsx
worddocument.docx
worddocument2.docx

As of right now, my code creates a text file that generates a list of ALL files in a specified folder.
I could use an "if" statement to get specific file extension, but I don't think this achieves the results I want. In this case, I would have to create a function for each Group (i.e. function for the image, adobe, microsoft and webdev groups). I want to be able to combine these groups freely (i.e. image and microsoft files in a list).

Example of an "if" statement:

```
for elem in os.listdir(filepath):
    if elem.endswith('.jpg'):
        listItem = elem + '\n'
        listName = filepath + (r"\{}List.txt".format(name))
        writeFile = open(listName, 'a')
        writeFile.write(listItem)
        writeFile.close()
    if elem.endswith('.png'):
        listItem = elem + '\n'
        listName = filepath + (r"\{}List.txt".format(name))
        writeFile = open(listName, 'a')
        writeFile.write(listItem)
        writeFile.close()
    if elem.endswith('.gif'):
        listItem = elem + '\n'
        listName = filepath + (r"\{}List.txt".format(name))
        writeFile = open(listName, 'a')
        writeFile.write(listItem)
        writeFile.close()
    else:
        continue
```

Full code without the "if" statement (generates a .txt file with all filenames from a specified folder):

```
import os

def enterFilePath():
    global filepath
    filepath = input("Please enter your file path. ")
    os.chdir(filepath)

enterFilePath()

def enterFileName():
    global name
    global listName
    name = str(input("Name the txt file. "))
    listName = name + ".txt"

enterFileName()

def listGenerator():
    for filename in os.listdir(filepath):
        listItem = filename + ' \n'
        listName = filepath + (r"\{}List.txt".format(name))
        writeFile = open(listName, 'a')
        writeFile.write(listItem)
        writeFile.close()

listGenerator()
```

Comment: Idea: Create a dictionary with file extensions as key and list of files as value. Then you can populate your dictionary with your loop, and afterwards you can write to the textfile whatever you want to. Edit: You might need another dictionary, where keys are your categories (microsoft, webdev, etc) and the corresponding extensions as values, and then combine the two dicts.

Comment: `global` variables are bad. Don't use them. If your function generates a value, `return` it instead of writing it to a global variable.

Answer (score 1):

A pointer before getting into the answer - avoid using `global` in favor of function parameters and `return` values. It will make debugging significantly less of a headache and make it easier to follow data flow through your program.

nostradamus is correct in his comment, a `dict` will be the ideal way to solve your problem here. I've also done similar things as your issue before using [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) and [`pathlib.Path`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/pathlib.html), which I'll be using here.

First, the dict:

```
groups = {
    'image': {'jpg', 'png', 'gif'},
    'adobe': {'pdf', 'raw'},
    'microsoft': {'docx', 'pptx', 'xlsx'},
    'webdev': {'js', 'html', 'css'}
}
```

This sets up your extension groups that you mentioned, which you can then access easily with `groups['image']`, `groups['adobe']`, etc.

Then, using the `Path.glob` method, `itertools.chain.from_iterable`, and a comprehension, you can get your list of desired files in a single statement (or function).

```
# Set up some variables
target_groups = ['adobe', 'webdev']

# Initialize generator
files = chain.from_iterable(
    # Glob pattern for the current extension
    Path(filepath).glob(f'*.{ext}')
    # Each group in target_groups
    for group in target_groups
    # Each extension in current group
    for ext in groups[group]
)

# Then, just iterate the files
for fpath in files:
    # Do stuff with file here
    print(fpath.name)
```

My test directory has one file of each extension you listed, named `a`, `b`, etc for each group. Using the above code, my output is:

```
a.pdf
b.raw
a.js
b.html
c.css
```

The way the file list/generator is set up means that the list of files will be sorted by extension-group, then by extension, and then by name. If you want to change what groups are being listed, just add/remove values in the `target_groups` list above (works with a single option as well).

You'll also want to consider parameterizing your targets, such as through `input` or script arguments, as well as handling cases where a requested group doesn't exist in the groups dictionary. The code above would probably also be more useful as a function, but I'll leave that implementation up to you :)